# Execute except section EITHER if exception occurs OR if a specific condition occurs

Tags: delphi

I want to execute the `except` section **EITHER IF** (res = 1) **OR** if DoSomething creates an exception:

```
try
  res := DoSomething;
except      
  DoExceptionCode;      
end;
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `except` blocks runs only when an exception is raised inside the `try` block.  So, if `DoSomething()` does not raise an exception, simply raise your own Exception instead, eg:

```pascal
try
  res := DoSomething;
  if res = 1 then raise Exception.Create('error message');
except
  DoExceptionCode;
end;
```

Otherwise, do something more like this instead:

```pascal
try
  res := DoSomething;
except      
  res := 1;
end;
if res = 1 then
  DoErrorCode;
```

Comment: I believed that it is not allowed to MANUALLY raise an exception (with `raise`) in the `try` block.

Comment: You can `raise` an exception wherever you want (including an `except` block).

Comment: @user1580348 A `try` block would be pretty useless if code inside the block could not manually `raise` an exception. There would be no point in even having `raise` and `try` in the language! You may want to read up on the documentation: [Exceptions (Delphi)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Exceptions_(Delphi))

Comment: @user1580348 It also seems that you're trying to use exceptions for flow control which [is not considered as a good practice](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why).